# Wordpress signup page doesn't show on freelanceengine theme

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've justed purchased wordpress theme called "freelanceengine"
What I want is to make changes to that theme, exactly login and signup page.
After theme installation, I tried to find signup page or link in source and database for several hours, but not found yet :(

Looking for somebody who have experienced similar problem.

[Please have a look at this screenshot where I expect to see "Sign Up" link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRiMt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you didn't set "users_can_register" in your theme options.
Try this sql in your mysql console:

UPDATE `wp`.`wp_options` SET `option_value` = '1' WHERE `option_name` = `users_can_register`;

It worked for me :)